# template type template specialization by value

Tags: c++, template-specialization

How do I define a `Foo<n>` to be a `Foo<X<n>>` for `int n`?

```cpp
template<int n> struct X{};
template<typename T> struct Foo{};

template<int n>
using Foo<n> = Foo<X<n>>;

int main(){
    Foo<3> a;   // same as Foo<X<3>>
    Foo<X<3>> b;    
}
```

I tried `using`, type traits conditionals, default template arguments, renaming of Foo. I would know how to solve it with `Foo<void,int>` by using a default argument in Foo and a conditional using statement; but I'd like to achieve a solution that requires no change of `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The kind of template argument expect by `Foo` according to your declaration `template<typename T> struct Foo{};` is a *type*. You can't make it a *non-type*.

You also can't declare another class, class template, type alias or alias template with the same name in the same scope.

Even if you use different scopes, `Foo` can only find one of these entities with the same name from the same scope. You can't see both of the at the same time. There is no "overload resolution" for class/alias templates.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept that answer. Add on: What if I accept ``Bar<n>`` instead of ``Foo<n>``. That seems more favorable than ``Foo<void,n>``. Is there a solution then? (It seems neither ``using`` nor ``typedef`` can be employed with templates.)

Comment: @DarikaRanganathan `template<int n>
using Bar = Foo<X<n>>;`.

Comment: Ah, I am so blind... Thanks !! :)